# Override UrlHelper.RouteUrl

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I'm building a site using NopCommerce 2.30. Out of the box, the product URLs look like this:

```
/p/16/build-your-own-computer/
```

I've made some changes to get the URLs looking like this:

```
/build-your-own-computer/
```

I've made a change to a `Route` to stop it from using the `Id` parameter. However, all the links across the site are still passing the Id parameter through the `Url.RouteUrl` method:

```
@Url.RouteUrl("Product", new { productId = Model.Id, SeName = Model.SeName })
```

This results in the following URL:

```
/build-your-own-computer/?productId=16
```

I could just go through and remove the `productId` parameter from the method call. However, some plugins also add links containing the `productId`, which I'm unable to change.

Is there a way I can override the `Url.RouteUrl` method to do a check for requests to the product `Route` and then remove the `productId`?

Comment: Umm - how would your controller/action know what product Id has been clicked by the user if you are not passing an Id in the Url?

Comment: Rather than using the product Id to get the product, it uses the product name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to resolve my issue using a slightly modified solution of this: http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/03/removing-route-values-from-linksurls-in.html

Robert's solution didn't include namespaces so I made a few adjustments below:

```
public static class CustomRouteExtensions
{

    public static Route MapRoute(this RouteCollection routes, string name, string url, string excludeRouteValueNames, object defaults)
    {
        return MapRoute(routes, name, url, excludeRouteValueNames, defaults, null, null);
    }

    public static Route MapRoute(this RouteCollection routes, string name, string url, string excludeRouteValueNames, object defaults, string[] namespaces)
    {
        return MapRoute(routes, name, url, excludeRouteValueNames, defaults, null, namespaces);
    }

    public static Route MapRoute(this RouteCollection routes, string name, string url, string excludeRouteValueNames, object defaults, object constraints)
    {
        return MapRoute(routes, name, url, excludeRouteValueNames, defaults, constraints, null);
    }

    public static Route MapRoute(this RouteCollection routes, string name, string url, string excludeRouteValueNames, object defaults, object constraints, string[] namespaces)
    {
        if (routes == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("routes");

        if (url == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("url");

        Route item = new CustomRoute(url, new MvcRouteHandler(), excludeRouteValueNames)
        {
            Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary(defaults),
            Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary(constraints),
            DataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary()
        };

        if ((namespaces != null) && (namespaces.Length > 0))
            item.DataTokens["Namespaces"] = namespaces;

        routes.Add(name, item);

        return item;
    }

}
```

My custom `Route` then looks like this:

```
public class CustomRoute : Route
{

    #region Properties

    public ReadOnlyCollection<string> ExcludedRouteValuesNames { get; private set; }

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public CustomRoute(string url, IRouteHandler routeHandler, string commaSeparatedRouteValueNames)
        : this(url, routeHandler, (commaSeparatedRouteValueNames ?? string.Empty).Split(','))
    {
    }

    public CustomRoute(string url, IRouteHandler routeHandler, params string[] excludeRouteValuesNames)
        : base(url, routeHandler)
    {
        ExcludedRouteValuesNames = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(excludeRouteValuesNames.Select(val => val.Trim()).ToList());
    }

    #endregion

    #region Route overrides

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        if (requestContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("requestContext");

        // create new route data and include only non-excluded values
        var excludedRouteData = new RouteData(this, this.RouteHandler);

        // add route values
        requestContext.RouteData.Values
            .Where(pair => !this.ExcludedRouteValuesNames.Contains(pair.Key, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(pair => excludedRouteData.Values.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value));

        // add data tokens
        requestContext.RouteData.DataTokens
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(pair => excludedRouteData.DataTokens.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value));

        // intermediary request context
        var currentContext = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current), excludedRouteData);

        // create new URL route values and include only none-excluded values
        var excludedRouteValues = new RouteValueDictionary(
            values
                .Where(v => !this.ExcludedRouteValuesNames.Contains(v.Key, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value)
        );

        var result = base.GetVirtualPath(currentContext, excludedRouteValues);

        return result;
    }

    #endregion

}
```

My new `Route.MapRoute` looks like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("Product", 
                "{SeName}", 
                "productIdd", 
                new { controller = "Catalog", action = "UrlType" }, 
                new[] { "Nop.Plugin.FreshEgg.Seo.Controllers" });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to override RouteUrl. It takes in a collection of key/value pairs. Just modify the route so it no longer expects the id and remove the id from the @Url.RouteUrl call. You will need to create a route that accepts URLs like the following:

`/p/{productName}`

You can do that in your Global.asax:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Products",
    "/p/{productName}",
    new { controller = "Products", action = "Details" }
);
```

Now you would generate a route like this instead:

```
@Url.RouteUrl("Products", new { productName = Model.SeName })
```

Now in your controller you have to additional work to find a product from a name instead of an id. It will probably look something like this now instead:

```
 public ActionResult Details(string productName)
 {
     var product = ProductRepository.FindByName(productName);

     return View(product);
 }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. This is what I'm already doing, however, all of the `@Url.RouteUrl` occurrences are still sending the `productId` through. Because the `productId` isn't part of the `Route`, it adds it as a query string parameter to the end of the link. I need to stop it from adding the query string parameter without removing it from the `@Url.RouteUrl`.

Comment: @Scrooby Is there any code of yours that is expecting this id to be passed in? Is it okay that it is passed in to the call to Url.RouteUrl but not to the controller?

Comment: @Dismissle I am using the Id in other places in the view so removing it from the controller wouldn't be an option.